# Remapping/assign some hardware keys for Microsoft natural ergonomic keyboard 4000

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, button-remapping

Recently I bought Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000.

Microsoft® Mouse and Keyboard Center allows to remap/assign some specific keys, but some keys like central "star" button, or zoom in/out button cannot be reassigned, but only enabled/disabled.

I tried to reassign these keys using Sharpkeys, but this program does not recognize them: if I type these keys it do not show anything is type mode.

If I run Microsoft keyboard diagnostics and type these keys there, they are displayed as "HID Input" without any keycode.

So is there any way to remap/assign star and zoom in/out keys?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The Zoom key can be mapped to scroll up or down as can be seen [here](https://superuser.com/questions/195474/change-zoom-action-to-scroll-in-a-ms-natural-keyboard-4000) it's very useful and is working on Windows 7, 10 (I didn't try on Windows 11).

Regarding the star key I did not manage any way to remap it.

Answer (score 0):

The latest 2023 solution that worked was to simply update the command file for the two key actions related to zoom and make them scroll in the commands.xml file at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center, in the  section.

```
  <C319 Type="6" Activator="ScrollUp" />
  <C320 Type="6" Activator="ScrollDown" />
```